# Python SyntaxError at end of code

Tags: python, syntax-error

I keep getting the same error for the following code:

Here is a similar error if I was to delete the print statement

```
File "./MIcalc.py", line 31

                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know it is saying that there is a syntax error at the end of the file, but I have no idea how to correct it:/

I am using python 2.7 and error persists for any line of code at line 31

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
DIR = '/home/sbird/lobSTR/output/output.txt'

def makeAlleleList(ALLREADS):
    alleleList = []
    ALLREADS_split = ALLREADS.split(";")
    allele = [x.split("|") for x in ALLREADS_split]
    [alleleList.append(x[0]) for x in allele]
    return alleleList

def makeCovThresh(ALLREADS):
    covThreshList = 0
    ALLREADS_split = ALLREADS.split(";")
    allele = [x.split("|") for x in ALLREADS_split]
    for x in allele:
            covThreshHold += int(x[1])
    return covThreshList

f = open("write_MI_out.txt","w")

for line in open(DIR):
    column = line.split("\t")
    ALLREADS = column[2].split("'")
    motherList = makeAlleleList(ALLREADS[1])
    fatherList = makeAlleleList(ALLREADS[3])
    sonList = makeAlleleList(ALLREADS[5])
    covThresh = makeCovThresh(ALLREADS[5])
    if len(sonList) < 3:
            if set(motherList) & set(fatherList) & set(sonList):
                    f.write("{0} \n".format(covThresh)
                    print "wrote to file"
f.close()
print "Fin."
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~
```

Comment: I've come across times where caught errors say they are on a specific line when they are actually on a line or two above where it says they are. Include all your code at least 10 lines up from where the error says

Comment: Am I missing a closed parenthesis?
I am working in vim, do I just need to re write the code into another saved file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
                f.write("{0} \n".format(covThresh)
```

You're missing a parenthesis here.

```
                f.write("{0} \n".format(covThresh))
```